# How i can compare columns from another dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes:
First with AVG values:

```
+----------+-----+  
| Category | AVG |  
+----------+-----+  
| Categ    | 1.0 |  
+----------+-----+  
| Categ2   | 0.5 | 
+----------+-----+
...
```

...
Second has the fallowing category: Category, Name, Price
The question is:
How can I delete all those records for which the price is less than the average price from the first table??
I tried that way:

```
dataGreaterAvge = data.where(data.Price >= avgCategoryPrice.where(data.Category == avgCategoryPrice.Category).collect()[0]["avg(Price)"])

dataGreaterAvge  - First dataframe
data - Second dataframe
```

However, this does not work as it should, because it only takes the value of the first element from the average values table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark works like SQL... so...

First you need to join the dataframes.

```
a = df1.alias('a')
b = df2.alias('b')
df_joined = a.join(b, a.Category == b.Category)
```

then you will be able to filter properly

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df_joined.select(col('a.category'),col('a.AVG'))\
         .where(col('a.AVG') > f.avg(col('b.avg')).groupBy(col('a.AVG'))
```

Comment: can I do it without joining?